# Why does "while(true)" with "Thread.sleep" cause 100% CPU usage?

Tags: java, while-loop, cpu-usage

**update:** I don't know why but it suddenly turn out to be fine. Now that the program's cpu usage is just 10%~17%.

---

I'm making a linux background problem in java.
The problem should execute every 100 seconds.
So I make a timer class and some code like below:

```
while(true) {   
  try {
    Thread.sleep(1000 * 100);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }           
}
```

But it still fills up the cpu usage.

That's the whole main(). No other program are running.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws WeiboException, HttpException, IOException{
  timer = new Timer(true);
  timer.schedule(new Getdatatimer(), 0, 100 * 1000);

  System.out.print("runnning \n");  
  while(true) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000 * 100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }             
  }
}
```

the timer accurately run every 100sec. But the question is cpu usage.

Comment: That code alone should not cause "100% CPU" (unless there is an obscene amount if InterruptedExceptions) -- what other threads are running? Are you 100% sure that code is the code run and there isn't a stale class floating about?

Comment: What happens when you put: `System.out.println("hi! " + System.currentTimeMillis());` on the line right above the `Thread.sleep`? Does it print "hi!" the expected number of times with the expected "millis" interval? I have a suspicion that the executed JAR/class is not being rebuilt correctly.

Comment: What do you do in getdatatimer()? If you are scheduling something again in the timerTask with initial delay as 0 you may get into infinite loop.

Comment: The CPU usage shouldn't be 1% for this process. If you use `top` you can see what this process is doing and not confuse it with what the rest of the system is doing.

Comment: this is odd because I'm seeing exactly the same behaviour (this is Java 8). Profiling it (JProfiler) across Linux and Windows machines show the same thing; a Thread.sleep(X) sits there at 100% CPU. The application remains responsive and it's not starved so it must be running at the lowest possible priority but it's still very strange. Did you upgrade Java versions or make any OS upgrades/changes before it suddenly started working? And also; the CPU profile goes from < 1% to 100% by switching on the Thread Which Sleeps (tm) - it alone is to blame

Answer (score 5):

Your code seems fine, it should not cause busy wait. May be something else is consuming cpu, you can determine that by using a profiler or checking stacktraces in jconsole, jvisualvm.